# .bat file stops my powershell script from working correctly

Tags: powershell

So I have a .bat file that will run my powershell script with hidden window cause its all displayed with gui.

```
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%"\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe (
    "%ProgramFiles%"\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -windowstyle hidden .\ZscalerPosture.ps1
) ELSE (
    Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden .\ZscalerPosture.ps1
)
```

Now its meant to look like this:

[image]

but instead it doesn't change the numbers or color:

[image]

Now the code that changes the number and color is:

```
$DetailsText1.Text = ($properties)[1]
if (($properties)[1] -eq 1) {
    $DetailsText1.BackColor = '#43eb34'
}Else{
    $DetailsText1.BackColor = 'Red'
}


$DetailsText2.Text = ($properties)[3]
if (($properties)[3] -eq 1) {
    $DetailsText2.BackColor = '#43eb34'
}Else{
    $DetailsText2.BackColor = 'Red'
}

$DetailsText3.Text = ($properties)[5]
if (($properties)[5] -eq 1) {
    $DetailsText3.BackColor = '#43eb34'
}Else{
    $DetailsText3.BackColor = 'Red'
}

$DetailsText4.Text = ($properties)[7]
if (($properties)[7] -eq 1) {
    $DetailsText4.BackColor = '#43eb34'
}Else{
    $DetailsText4.BackColor = 'Red'
}

$DetailsText5.Text = ($properties)[9]
if (($properties)[9] -eq 1) {
    $DetailsText5.BackColor = '#43eb34'
}Else{
    $DetailsText5.BackColor = 'Red'
}

$DetailsText6.Text = ($properties)[11]
if (($properties)[11] -eq 1) {
    $DetailsText6.BackColor = '#43eb34'
}Else{
    $DetailsText6.BackColor = 'Red'
}


$DetailsText1.Refresh()
$DetailsText2.Refresh()
$DetailsText3.Refresh()
$DetailsText4.Refresh()
$DetailsText5.Refresh()
$DetailsText6.Refresh()
```

(note: yes its very messy right now I am cleaning it up)

Extra note: if i run the file normally (right click > run with powershell) it works fine

Answer (score 0):

So the reason its not working is because the .bat tries to open in powershell 7 and for some reason the code doesnt like that. So instead the .bat file will look like

```
Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden .\ZscalerPosture.ps1
```

This will open the GUI without the powershell showing and work as intended.